# No page break between sections in scrbook

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, scrbook

I have a document which uses scrbook as documentclass. Chapters are in the main document, whereas sections are in separate files and included via \input{filename}. As far as I understand neither scrbook nor \input should cause a page break between sections, however my document does. I tried to put two sections in one file to see if this behavior comes from \input, but it does not. Does scrbook by default start sections on new pages? Subsections are continued on the same page, as they should.

Can you tell me, if I misunderstand the default behavior of scrbook, or if I must be including a pagebreak between sections without knowing?

The code is quite complex by now, so I do not know, what to attach.

Remark: I used \clearpage between the \input-commands before and removed those, but that did not change a thing.

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Petra

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt,openany,DIV=calc,ngerman,twocolumn,xcolor=dvipsnames,draft]{scrbook}

\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\geometry{
    tmargin=10mm,
    bmargin=20mm,
    lmargin=10mm,
    rmargin=20mm,
        headheight=0pt
    }
\setlength{\columnsep}{6mm}

\usepackage[frame,width=216mm, height=303mm,center,noaxes,noinfo]{crop}

\usepackage{suffix}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}           
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[german]{babel}

\setlength{\footskip}{35pt}
\setlength{\footheight}{20pt}

\usepackage[
  manualmark,
  headsepline=0pt,
  footsepline=0pt,
  draft=false
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ofoot*{\pagemark}
\ifoot*{\headmark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{pagination}{}

\setlength\textfloatsep{10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}

\begin{document}

\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}

\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{3}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\addchap{Chapter-One}
\label{chap:one}
\clearpage

\twocolumn[\section*{Section 1}\label{sec1}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 1}
\lipsum[30]

\twocolumn[\section*{Section 2}\label{sec2}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 2}
\lipsum[30]


\addchap{Chapter-Two}
\label{chap:two}
\clearpage

\twocolumn[\section*{Section 3}\label{sec3}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 3}
\lipsum[30]

\twocolumn[\section*{Section 4}\label{sec4}]
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Section 4}
\lipsum[30]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `scrbook` does *not* start sections on new pages automatically. The section heading goes to a new page if the previous page is filled or if the material following the section heading is too heigh for the previous page. Note that there will never be a page break after the section heading.

Comment: Ok, then at least I did not misinterpret the default behavior. I will try to minimize my script to show the problem...

Comment: you definitely use `\input` and not `\include` to include the sections? (`\include` would cause a page break)

Comment: Yes, I use input. But as I said, I even tried without separate files and it still gives the same behavior. I attach a more or less minimal script, that shows the problem...

Comment: Ok, I attached the script. As you will see, the Chapter titles are on their own pages, which is perfectly fine, as those get some graphics in my full script. But Section 1 and 2 (and 3 and 4 again) are on separate pages, although there is an awful lot of space, so they could be on the same page.

Comment: @Petra the problem is not related to your section, but that `\twocolumn` starts on a new page. You can see this with `\addchap{Chapter-One}
\twocolumn
test`

Comment: You are right, if I switch to onecolumn mode everything is fine. So simple, so bad. Is there any workaround for that? I have some long section titles that should run over both columns.

Comment: I attached a picture of the page layout I would like to have. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: Every `\twocolumn` command issues a page break.

Comment: Can one make a workaround with minipage or force the section title to be full width in a different way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `multicol` package to create your desired layout:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[2]
\end{multicols}

\section*{Very long section title that spans both columns}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]